# Node.js connection error server is running but page is not loading

Tags: javascript, node.js

The server is running without any errors. but the page is constantly loading and stays on. Then I get the error 'Incomplete response received from application.

[Console Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0zRA.png)

App.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const app = express()
const hostname = '127.0.0.1'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const mongo = require('mongodb')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
const expressSession = require('express-session')
const connectMongo = require('connect-mongo')
const methodOverride = require('method-override')
const limit = require('./helpers/limit').limit
const truncate = require('./helpers/truncate').truncate
const paginate = require('./helpers/paginate').paginate

const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://siber_haber:myapppass@siberhabercomm.sspd3.mongodb.net/Siberhabercomm?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});

const mongoStore = connectMongo(expressSession)

app.use(expressSession({
  secret: 'testo test',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new mongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}))

app.use(fileUpload())
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))

// handle-bars helpers

const hbs = exphbs.create({
  helpers: {
    limit: limit,
    truncate: truncate,
    paginate: paginate
  }
})

app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine)
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

// DISPLAY LINK MIDDLEWARE

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const {userId} = req.session
  if(userId) {
    res.locals = {
      displayLink : true
    }
  } else {
      res.locals = {
        displayLink : false
    }
  }
  next()
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.sessionFlash = req.session.sessionFlash
  delete  req.session.sessionFlash
  next()
})


const main = require('./routes/main')
const post = require('./routes/posts')
const users = require('./routes/users')
const admin = require('./routes/admin/index')
app.use('/', main)
app.use('/posts', post)
app.use('/users', users)
app.use('/admin', admin)


app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(` Server Çalışıyor http://${hostname}:${port}`)
})
```

Please help me understand where the error is
i think the error is from the database code. i'm not so sure.
Node version v10.24.1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What URL does the problem occur on?  Can you show all the code involved in handling the request for that URL?